# Symfony 3.4 - Expected Entity got EntityManager API REST

Tags: php, json, api, symfony, symfony-3.4

I'm creating an API REST and I want to set for `$userInterest` an Entity named `Category` (*many to one*) I did the same thing for the `User` entity (*and I set the "Profile" entity*), but the `Profile` entity is passed as parameter and it's created in this function so it's simple and it works.

I do it like this:

```
/**
 *
 * @Rest\Post(
 *     path = "/users/register",
 *     name = "api_users_add"
 * )
 * @Rest\View(StatusCode=201, serializerGroups={"user_detail"})
 * @ParamConverter(
 *     "user",
 *     converter="fos_rest.request_body",
 *     options={"deserializationContent"={"groups"={"Deserialize"}}},
 * )
 * @ParamConverter(
 *     "profile",
 *     converter="fos_rest.request_body",
 *     options={"deserializationContent"={"groups"={"Deserialize"}}},
 * )
 * @ParamConverter(
 *     "userInterest",
 *     converter="fos_rest.request_body",
 *     options={"deserializationContent"={"groups"={"Deserialize"}}},
 * )
 */
public function postUserAction(Request $request, User $user, Profile 
$profile, UserInterest $userInterest) {

    $profile->setLastConnexion(new \DateTime('now'));
    $profile->setCreatedAccount(new \DateTime('now'));

    $user->setIdProfile($profile);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($profile);
    $em->flush();

    $this->encodePassword($user);
    $user->setRoles([User::ROLE_USER]);

    $this->persistUser($user);
 }
```

-

So the previus example works really well but when I try to set the `Category` entity for `$userInterest` that don't work (*also category is already created it's like a "static" table*) so the problem is how can I set `Category` for `$userInterest` knowing that in the previous example the entity is created in the function and in this example the entity is already created so I tried:

```
    $em_category = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em_category->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->findOneBy(array('id' => ($request->get('id_category'))));

    $userInterest->setCategory($em_category);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($userInterest);
    $em->flush();
```

But that makes the error:

> "Expected value of type "AppBundle\Entity\Category" for association >field "AppBundle\Entity\UserInterest#$category", got >"Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager" instead."

How can i set the entity category and not the entity manager ...?

The JSON sent (*if that can help*) :

```
{
"username": "Usertest",
"password": "strenghtpassword",
"email": "thxforall@symfony.com",
"birth": "1999-04-26T18:25:43-05:00",
"content": "I like Netflix",
"id_category": "1"
}
```

In category table the ID:1 as the content "what do you like" for example.

Comment: `Unknown column 't0.content_c' in 'field list'`.

Comment: i don't understand the error i don't have filed list ...

Comment: The part that says "SQL" doesn't tell you it's something to do with database and you trying to get a field that's not there?

Comment: i refresh sql database and the error gone but now i have : Expected value of type "AppBundle\Entity\Category" for association field "AppBundle\Entity\UserInterest#$category", got "Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager" instead.

Comment: how can i set the entity to userinterest and not the entitymanager ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because you never assign `$em_catagory` with the `findOneBy` and it still an entity manager object. Try this :

```
$em_category = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$category = $em_category->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->findOneBy(array('id' => ($request->get('id_category'))));

$userInterest->setCategory($category);

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($userInterest);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: Quick, simple, and that work thank you sooo mutch i just start symfony so i do a lot of quick mistakes like this one thx you bro